# ¿Cómo crear una conexión remota PSSession y ejecutar un comando en el equipo remoto?

Tags: java, powershell

Buen día, tengo un problema al momento de querer correr un comando de powershell en un servidor remoto, he probado haciendo el proceso manualmente en cmd comando por comando y obtengo el resultado que quiero, pero al momento de hacerlo en java no hace lo que quiero, mi clase java es esta:

```
String command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell C:\\scr.ps1";

 Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

 powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
          String line;
          System.out.println("Standard Output:");
          BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
          while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
          }
          stdout.close();
          //En caso de error se obtiene
          System.out.println("Standard Error:");
          BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
          while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
          }
          stderr.close();
          System.out.println("Done");
```

Como se ve en el comando simplemente ejecuto powershell y ejecuto un script, anteriormente tenia todos los comandos en esa variable pero generaba muchos errores por lo que decidi meterlos en un script, el contenido del script es el siguiente:

```
$pass = convertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -force

$cred = new-object System.management.Automation.PSCredential("user",$pass)

Enter-Pssession -ComputerName User-Pc -Credential $cred

dir
```

en los 2 primeros comando seteo el usuario y contraseña que se usaran para establecer la conexión, estos pasos los hace sin problemas, y la sintaxis es correcta ya los probé y funcionan a la perfección el problema viene cuando ejecuta el comando *dir*, ese comando debería ser ejecutado en el equipo remoto ya que con los comando anteriores se conecta, pero al ejecutarlo se corre en mi equipo local y no tengo idea del ¿por qué? como he dicho ya probe haciendolos manualmente en el cmd y funciona, agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que puedes resolverlo utilizando lo siguiente:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -Credential domain\user -ScriptBlock {command}
```

O sea que el script quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$pass = convertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -force
$cred = new-object System.management.Automation.PSCredential("user",$pass)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "User-Pc" -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {dir}
```

*PD:*

No pude probarlo, pero por lo que leí puede venir por ahí el problema.

Comment: muchas gracias, funciona perfecto